# Unable to reset xcode theme/ color scheme

Tags: xcode, themes, restore

I accidentally changed the default theme "dracula" and now cannot change it back.
i tried the method to add a new theme which would choose from original sources but it does not show the option for the same. any ideas?
please refer to the image below for further details
thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Dracula** is not a default Xcode theme from apple (I don't have it in my Xcode version *10.1 (10B61)*), so maybe you need to re-install the original template.

You can find more info in the following link:
https://draculatheme.com/xcode/